# Applescript to open .url files on OS X Firefox

Tags: macos, url, applescript

For reasons that only the developers can understand, Firefox will create and open .url files on Windows and .webloc files on OS X but won't allow the Windows version of Firefox to open .webloc files or the OS X version of Firefox to open .url files. (.url files open in Safari but that's not good enough for reasons that aren't worth going into here.) As part of my efforts to use either filetype on either system, I'm writing an applescript to open .url files on OS X Firefox.

```
on open the_droppings
    set filePath to the_droppings

    set fp to open for access filePath
    set fileContents to read fp
    close access fp

    set secondLine to paragraph 2 of fileContents

    set tid to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "="
    set URLstring to last text item of secondLine
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tid

    tell application "Firefox"
        activate
        OpenURL URLstring
    end tell
end open
```

I thought this would work but in the 3rd to last line it says "Expected end of line, etc. but found identifier." Why is this?

**EDIT** sakra's answer below mostly works but breaks on urls containing "=" such as: http://example.com?foo=a&bar=z

Comment: To see how to open Windows .url files in OS X and OS X .webloc files in Windows: http://superuser.com/questions/54111/cross-platform-bookmark-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox does not seem to feature an AppleScript dictionary at all. Therefore the term `OpenURL` within the `tell app "Firefox"` statement is interpreted as an AppleScript identifier and not as an AppleScript command. Two AppleScript identifiers in a row result in a syntax error.

As a work-around you can use the shell command `open` in combination with the standard AppleScript command `do shell script`:

```
on open the_droppings

    set filePath to the_droppings

    set fileContents to read filePath

    set theOffset to offset of "URL=" in fileContents
    set URLstring to text (theOffset + 4) through -1 of fileContents

    do shell script "/usr/bin/open -a Firefox.app " & quoted form of URLstring
end open
```

Comment: Unfortunatly this script doesnt work for me as it takes the IDList part of the url file with it in the entered url in Firefox. Perhaps something that was introduced in Windows Vista or 7, but that is the reason why I made a new version of the script.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: download my script in an app here: http://www.mediafire.com/?v77bv9gl9e7oj40

This works even better:

```
on open the_droppings
    set filePath to the_droppings
    set fileContents to read filePath

    set theOffsetA to offset of "URL=" in fileContents
    set theOffsetB to offset of "IDList=" in fileContents
    set URLstring to text (theOffsetA + 4) through (theOffsetB - 3) of fileContents

    do shell script "/usr/bin/open -a Firefox.app " & quoted form of URLstring
end open
```

It reads the URL= line to the next line ( IDList ) minus 3 steps ( to ignore the \r\n ) and sends it to firefox. Works like a charm for me.
I however have seen url files with weird layout ( example: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=2619487 ), which I'm not sure of if it would work there. But I checked a lot of my url files and they dont have that, so atleast it works fine for me. Let me know if you run into troubles with this script. For the moment I'm setting it as default app to open URL files, instead of Safari!

To be able of opening url files with an applescript file, it needs to have the proper doctypes and identifier set in its plist, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations</key>
    <true/>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>url</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>document.icns</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>URL File</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeOSTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>URL</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>droplet</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>filehandler.url.mozilla.firefox</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>droplet</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>FirefoxURLHandler</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>dplt</string>
    <key>LSMinimumSystemVersionByArchitecture</key>
    <dict>
        <key>x86_64</key>
        <string>10.6</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score -1):

I know it's not apple script, but I did this to open them on Linux, but it has the problem that if and when the terminal closes, it kills the browser.  I opened another question about this, but this may help.

```
#!/bin/bash
#bash -c "cat $1 | grep URL | cut -d'=' -f2 | xargs firefox &"
echo OpenWinURL in firefox
echo Closing this window will close your firefox.
echo Try opening firefox before opening a OpenWinURL
#echo Copyright 2021 Aaron Peterson GPL V2 or later
#echo  The ampersand doesn't work after firefox
#echo "$1"
#
jobs -l
cat "$1" | grep  -m 1 URL= | cut -d'=' -f2- | xargs -0 -i firefox {} #&
jobs -l
disown -h -a
jobs -l
#read  -n 1 -p "Input Selection:" mainmenuinput

#echo testing
#wait 1000

#
#| head -n 1
#| cut -d'=' -f2 | xargs firefox &
```